# generate multiple reports in a single pdf using odt in xdocreport

Tags: java, velocity, odt, xdocreport

I am printing reports using odt with xdocreport in Java.

But now I want to print multiple reports of same document in a single pdf file using xdocreport.

Can any one can tell how to generate multiple reports in a single pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFMerger.html) and it's `PdfMergerUtility` class. Something like this.

```
PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
for (File singleReport: pdfReports) {
    pdfMerger.addSource(singleReport);
}
pdfMerger.setDestinationFileName("path/name");
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments();
```